# How to let a thread stop to do another task and then come back?

Tags: java, multithreading

> ATTENTION PLS: This may not be a real question in fact, just comes from my mind:)

In all programming langs, is there some ways to do this:

> A thread (named ThreadA) is doing a consume-time task (named TaskA).
>   When it achieves a part of TaskA, can we let it continue to do the rest when it finishes another task? In other words, can we let the thread `stop to do` another task and then comes back to `continue to do` the rest?

UPDATE:
Suppose we have two tasks  TaskA (Low priority) and TaskB (High priority). We are limited to create only one thread to do tasks. When the thread is doing TaskA, if higher priority task comes(such as TaskB), the thread must save the current status and to do the higher.

Comment: It could start another thread to perform the second task, and wait for it to complete.

Comment: I do not really understand what you want to achieve...
Threads are executing parallel, that is if Thread A is finished a part of its job, it could signal Thread B to do something on it....

Comment: @SteveSmith thank to your comment. If we just use a thread, can it do one more tasks concurrently?

Comment: Thread are there to do tasks concurrently.

Comment: @FdXing everying in your program executes line by line. If you wan't to do things concurrently, you'll need at least 2 threds. The one doing **taskA** an the other one doing **taskB**

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I update the question. Hope not to confuse you again.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're talking about are simply method calls in methods.

```
public void taskA() {
    int i = 1;
    i++;
    //DO other stuff
    System.out.println("Starting to work on other task")
    taskB(); //<------ This is what you're looking for
    System.out.println("Finished with other task. Now working on this task again")
    i++;
    System.out.println(i);
}

public void taskB() {
    System.out.println("This is from other task")
}
```

Comment: Well. There is no difference of running this in the main thread or a new separate thread.

Comment: @TomStein Thank to your comment. I update my question.  Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score -1):

I think that what he is looking for is wait and notify

```
wait() - Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object.

notify() - Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor.
```

or the suspend, stop, resume

found you a link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_control.htm

Comment: Thank to your comment @OferSkulsky. I update the question. Hope not to confuse you. Sorry for my poor english.